# Duplicate codes sent to user - SELECT FOR UPDATE

Tags: magento-1.9, database, object

Hi guys I am working an a site that sells electronic codes, the issue I am having is if two people order in the same few seconds they are BOTH sent the SAME codes.

I need a way editing it so when the collection of codes is loaded they are locked for that order so no other order can come in and use them.

I currently load codes in the following way from the database:

```
$qty = round($item->getQtyOrdered());
$codes = $this->getCollection()
      ->addFieldToFilter('codetype',array('like' => $sku))
      ->addFieldToFilter('codestatus', array('eq' => 0))
      ->setPageSize($qty)
      ->load();
```

This collection of codes are then passed on to another function which loops through them and adds them to the order etc.

I know I can manually do this via a direct query, but the rest of the plugin relies on this collection being loaded as a Magento object and if I do it direct I just get a normal array of results and not an object:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM codes WHERE used = 0 FOR UPDATE";
    /**
     * Get the resource model
     */
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

    /**
     * Retrieve the read connection
     */
    $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read')->fetchOne($query);
```

Can anyone advise me on how I can prevent this duplication of codes on orders?

Comment: did you get a solution for the problem?

Comment: No not yet, your snippet if hit by two customers at the same time loads the same "code" into the $codes collection and so they still end up with duplicate codes

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `used` column value to 1 once you get collection. (Assuming from your sql query)

```
$codes = $this->getCollection()
      ->addFieldToFilter('codetype',array('like' => $sku))
      ->addFieldToFilter('codestatus', array('eq' => 0))
      ->addFieldToFilter('used', array('eq' => 0))
      ->setPageSize($qty)
      ->load();
foreach($codes as $_code){
    $_code->setUsed(1)->save();
}
```

So with next collection it will only get codes which are set `used` value as `0`

Comment: Yes but if two orders both run at the same time, they both load the same code in $codes and will just set it to used :(